# The macro prints incorrect output

Tags: c

I'm learning C programming and this is my problem. I feel like I've learned the macro topic in C but I guess I'm not quite ready yet.

```
#define PGSIZE    4096 
#define CONVERT(sz)    (((sz)+PGSIZE-1) & ~(PGSIZE-1))

printf("0x%x", CONVERT(0x123456));
```

Here is the problem. My expected output is `0x100000000000` but it prints `0x124000`.

```
((sz)+PGSIZE-1) = (0x123456)+4096-1 
                = (0x123456)+(0x1000 0000 0000) - 1 //4096 is 2^12
                =  0x1000 0012 3456 - 1
                =  0x1000 0012 3455

~(PGSIZE-1) => ~(0x0111 1111 1111) = 0x1000 0000 0000

((sz)+PGSIZE-1) & ~(PGSIZE-1) = (0x1000 0012 3455) & (0x1000 0000 0000)
                              = 0x100000000000
```

But when I ran the program, it prints 0x124000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 0x100000000000 is 17592186044416, not 4096.

Comment: @JustSid Where is the number coming from???? And.. what is 4096 in hexadecimal? Could you explain it on answer if you don't mind? :)

Comment: 4096 in decimal is 0x1000 in hex, so PGSIZE-1 is 0xFFF.  I can't think how your example starting with 6 hex digits could be expected to end up with 12 hex digits.  Your macro rounds up to a multiple of 4096, and that's the result you see.  —— Oh, you say 4096 is 2^12 (which is correct) and show 1000 0000 0000 which is almost the binary representation (1 zero short), but not the hex representation.  So your interpretation of what's expected is all wrong.

Comment: Ahhh, that's where that number is coming from. Michael Petch and coderredoc also just pointed that out in my (now) deleted answer.

Comment: ???? the answer has been deleted while I was reading.

Comment: @JohnBaek It"s because the answer is exactly what Jonathan Leffler pointed out: You confused hex and binary

Comment: Thanks, you are right but how 0x124455 & 1000 becomes 0x124000? Does if automatically fill 1s to the front? And yes if you can reinstate your answer with more explanation it will be highly appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your calculation.
2^12 is not 1000 0000 0000, but 0001 0000 0000 0000.

The weights of binary begin as 2^0 which is one so 2^12 comes at 13th position so 4096 is 0x1000
 If you use this for your manual calculation you will get 0x124000 as your answer.

The below calculation also answers your doubt "how 0x124455 & 1000 becomes 0x124000? Does if automatically fill 1s to the front? Could you explain little more about it on the question?" in the comment of the previous answer.

```
4096 = 0x1000 
4096-1 => 0xfff => 0x0000 0fff
    ~(4096-1) is thus 0xfffff000

    Coming to the addition part in macro 
     (0x123456)+4096-1 
         =>0x123456+0x1000-1
         =>0x124456-1
         =>0x124455

    You result will be 0x124455 & 0xfffff000 which is 0x124000 which is the correct output
```

Comment: ~(0) = f. I got it but what about other numbers?

Comment: one more question... 0x1 & 0xF = 1. How is that be???? Can it be like 0x1 & 0xF = F???

Comment: You will find your answer here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-bitwise-operators-c/ Every bitwise operator is discussed here with examples and what output is got. Pay attention to the one on "~" which is what your doubt is about

Answer (score 2):

You showed in the question:

```
((sz)+PGSIZE-1) => (0x123456)+4096-1 
                =(0x123456)+(0x1000 0000 0000) - 1 //4096 is 2^12
                =0x1000 0012 3456 - 1
```

You converted 4096 to a binary notation, but then treat it as a hexadecimal number. That won't work. If you want to keep the hexadecimal notation, that's:

```
((sz)+PGSIZE-1) => (0x123456)+4096-1 
                =(0x123456)+(0x1000) - 1
                =0x124456 - 1
```

Or converting both to binary, that's:

```
((sz)+PGSIZE-1) => (0x123456)+4096-1 
                =(0b1_0010_0011_0100_0101_0110)+(0b1_0000_0000_0000) - 1
                = 0b1_0010_0100_0100_0101_0110 - 1
```

Comment: how 0x124455 & 1000 becomes 0x124000? Does if automatically fill 1s to the front? Could you explain little more about it on the question?